# Red5 unusable for serious streaming?

Tags: flash, video-streaming, red5

I am running Red5 V1 RC2, with the oflaDemo application and a simple application that I created that displays a video in a VideoPlayer component. I have found that Red5 sound and video are out of sync when playing any decent- length video (more than a few minutes in length).

The demo videos that come with the oflaDemo application play without problems. They are in sync. The problem arises when you try to play a longer video. In my application I am attempting to stream an mp4 video that is a little more than 45 minutes in length, and am seeing that the sound apparently starts well before the video and remains almost a minute ahead of the video information. Nothing I do seems able to put the sound back in sync with the video.

Thinking that there might have been something wrong with my code, I played the video using the oflaDemo. It has the same problem.

When played on any media player (on Windows, Linux, or Mac) the sound and video sync up without problems. There is nothing wrong with the video information.

For some reason, apparently on Red5 the sound information is being loaded before the video information, and the server is doing nothing to keep the two parts in sync.

This is a serious problem and appears to be a bug in Red5 streaming.

Has anyone else seen this problem? If so, has anyone figured out a workaround? Does anyone know if the Red5 people are working on a fix for this? If not, why not? Is there some way to get the sound and video synchronized in a Red5 video? Is there a cludge that can solve this problem?

Someone please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been a little while since I was involved with any Red5 coding, but I believe it has to do with a lack of metadata for proper syncing. Have you tried converting that mp4 to an FLV file? Red5 will automatically handle the metadata creation for an FLV, but not an mp4.

Also, I know the user groups and irc channel are a little thin, but if you lurk long enough you should be able to get more details from the horses mouth.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the swift response. Actually, Red5's forums, IRC, and other user mechanisms are not working and haven't been for several weeks. Otherwise, I would have asked my question there instead of here. I will try the conversion you suggest, though. Can you point me to a good (free) conversion application?

Comment: The Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder will do it, and do it well. It is free (or at least it was last time I used it). If they have bundled it or made it a pay-for app, you can always just use the 90 free trial to see if it will be a workable solution for you. I'm sure there are other converters as well, but I haven't the experience with any of them to confidently make a suggestion.

Comment: FFMPEG is an Open Source tool and it can also stream RTMP natively. However first of all FFMPEG is a converter tool. It is used in many video-projects. If you simply need to convert a video, or cut it or do some tricks with the sound of it, FFMPEG is your tool. Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder makes more sense if you want to broadcast HD/h264 content or you want to use some of the exclusive Adobe functionalities in streaming (that are not available in the Flash Player). For simply converting videos I don't think you would choose this tool.